# React Media Query needs refresh to show image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, materialize

I am using react-media (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) to handle different screen sizes. 
 The aim of using react-media:
 Just bigger screens should see the parallax image (using materializeCSS for parallax). 
 Problem:
If you resize the window, the image will disappear (how it should be) and when you go back to the bigger screen the place of the image is white. After refreshing the page the image is there again. I noticed it occurs every time when I use media and a javascript materializeCSS "package". 
 
How can I fix that?

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import picture from "../../image/Introduction.jpeg";
import Media from "react-media";

const Paralaxes = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const M = window.M;
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax");
    M.Parallax.init(elems, {});
  });

  return (
    <Media query={{ minWidth: 768 }}>
      {matches =>
        matches ? (
          <div className="parallax-container">
            <div className="parallax">
              <img src={picture} className="responsive-img" alt="background" />
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="divider black" />
          </div>
        )
      }
    </Media>
  );
};

export default Paralaxes;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try if this is because of the minWidth style you have set in <Media>

I think it acts like Media query.

Comment: I tested it with maxWidth and minWidth, both did not work.

Comment: The doc says to use like this
<Media queries={{
          small: "(max-width: 599px)",
          medium: "(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1199px)",
          large: "(min-width: 1200px)"
        }}>
          {matches => (
            <Fragment>
              {matches.small && <p>I am small!</p>}
              {matches.medium && <p>I am medium!</p>}
              {matches.large && <p>I am large!</p>}
            </Fragment>
          )}
        </Media>
You are declaring for only one size. Check